# Custom sharing icons - get url, encode uri & replace

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, social-networking

I have 4 icons on each page of a site to share the page you're on.  I want to grab the URL of the page you're on, encode it, and then plug it into the href attribute of each button.

```
var url = window.location.href;
var encodedUrl = encodeURIComponent(url);
var urlRegEx = new RegExp(encodedUrl,'g');

$(".social").each(function () {
    $(this).html(this.html().replace('sharethisurl',urlRegEx));
});

<div id="share">
    <a class="social" href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=sharethisurl&media=sharethisjpg&description=" target="_blank"><img src="images/pinterest.png" alt="pin this" /></a>
    <a class="social" href="http://www.houzz.com/imageClipperUpload?link=sharethisurl&source=button&hzid=28938&imageUrl=sharethisjpg" target="_blank"><img src="images/houzz.png" alt="add to houzz" /></a>
    <a class="social" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=sharethisurl" target="_blank"><img src="images/facebook.png" alt="like this" /></a>
    <a class="social" href="https://twitter.com/share?url=sharethisurl" target="_blank"><img src="images/twitter.png" alt="tweet this" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: `.html()` is the html *between* the element tags.  You just want to update the href attribute.  Just use `this.href` inside the `each()`

Comment: I tried replacing with $(this).href.replace('sharethisurl',urlRegEx); and still no love :(

Comment: I see you have it working, but this method would have needed `this.href = this.href.replace('sharethisurl',urlRegEx)`  href is a string property of the anchor element, which is `this` (not to be confused with `$(this)` )

Answer (score 2):

What you need is

```
var url = window.location.href,
    encodedUrl = encodeURIComponent(url);

$(".social").prop('href', function(index, current){
    return current.replace(/sharethisurl/g, encodedUrl);
});
```

---

Some of the issues in your code

- Regular expressions are used as the pattern to find when using the `replace` method (*so it should be the first argument*)
- `html()` returns the html contents of an element (*it will not return the actual tag that is matched, only its children nodes*)

Comment: Sexxxy.... works perfect.  I never would have figured that all out :)  Thank You!!!!